# Do we need the [trying-new-systems] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I stumbled upon the tag [trying-new-systems](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trying-new-systems). Sadly it has neither a tag wiki excerpt nor a full tag wiki, and I can't find any discussions about the tag to learn something about the reasoning behind the tag.

It's currently used for four questions:

- [Fate based minigames in a historic/fantasy realm?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58965/34863) was locked as "Shopping Request" - this is the earliest question with this tag
- [Any good, lightweight systems for a Borrowers-based RPG?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67451/34863) was closed as "Too Broad" because it didn't adhere to the "Shopping Request" guidelines of the time
- [New to roleplaying, how do I start off a sort of superhero game with my sister?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108732/34863) was closed as "Too Broad"
- [What GM preparation would help with a first try at Valiant Universe RPG?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90712/34863) is still open

Do we still need the tag? If so, could someone update the tag wiki to explain how the tag is supposed to be used? Most questions with the tag are closed and it seems to be from a time when shopping requests were allowed. Part of what [trying-new-systems](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trying-new-systems) seems to want to achieve could be already covered by [system-introduction](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-introduction) and the rest seems to be about shopping requests, which are off-topic.

Comment: I've removed the tag from those four questions it was on, in accordance with the community response below ([+15/-0 at time of writing](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7880/1204)). I've also marked this as a burninate request to keep the records of what we've burninated collected in one place, even though this wasn't written as an outright request to burninate the tag.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Destroy it

As it currently is, that tag seems to have two uses: shopping questions and trying a *particular* new system. The former is off-topic and the latter is better covered by the specific system tags, [new-gm](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-gm) if the GM is new to RPGs as whole, and [system-introduction](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-introduction) if the question specifically addresses picking up a new system. There's little value in keeping the [trying-new-systems](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trying-new-systems) tag along, although it could possibly be a synonym to the more defined [system-introduction](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-introduction) tag.

### Potential future usage

On a more abstract level, such a tag might have a purpose for questions concerning trying out more systems in a more abstract sense, not regarding a particular system. A good example: [How do I convince my group to try a new system without always having to DM it first?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58829/11660)

However, those questions are still covered by [system-introduction](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-introduction) so for there to be value in a separate tag, there'd need to be some distinction between the two, and I can't think of any at this time. Let it burn.

Comment: I am not sure about the [tag:new-gm] tag. The tag wiki says that it should be used to categorize questions that are *inherently* about being new to GM-ing, while specific systems should consider [tag:system-introduction]...

Comment: @Secespitus Excellent, I don't remember seeing that tag before but it adds a lot to this. Thanks!

Comment: Hah, at this time I noticed it's in the question I linked myself. I'm not too good at this am I.